# How to make a MySQL select for a tree structure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL:

```
id       name        parent_id
1        animals       null
2        mammal         1
3        feline         2
4        human          2
5        cat            3
6        invertebrate   1
7        snake          6
8        objects        null
etc..
```

I want a MySQL query that displays the results in this order:

```
    Animals
       Mammal
          Feline
             Cat
          Human
       Invertebrate
    Objects
etc..
```

I'm still learning and am completely stuck with this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display a tree structure with an indefinite number of nested levels, I think you'll need to use mysql "within" some other language. With mysql and PHP this can be done with a couple nested "while" and "if" loops. But as Iouri says, a "purely" Mysql approach such as joining the table back to itself, will only support as many nesting levels as the number of joins you have.

```
SELECT 
    t1.name, t2.name, t3.name
FROM table t1
    JOIN table t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
    JOIN table t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id
    # etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
http://sqllessons.com/categories.html
```

I think it assumes that you have a set number of nesting levels though.

Comment: Or upgrade to a DBMS that properly supports these kind of queries ;)